# Removing multiple characters from string and spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

Hey guys I'm trying to remove two characters and any white space from a string that looks like this.

```
var num1 = "34 345 324.34 $"
var num2 = "$34,345,324.34"
```

I basically want to remove `$` and `,` and white space

so far I have this

```
num1.replace(/,|\s/g,""); //34345324.34$
num2.replace(/,|\s/g,""); //$34345324.34
```

How do I also delete the `$`

Thank you.

Comment: `replace(/[$,\s]/g,"")`

Comment: `.replace(/[$,\s]+/g, "");`

Comment: Wouldn't it be more robust to just *keep* numerals and decimal points? E.g. `num2.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be dealing with *currency* strings. You may follow your blacklist approach and use `.replace(/[,\s$]+/g,"")` to remove all occurrences of 1+ commas, whitespaces and dollar symbols. However, once you have a pound, euro, yen, etc. currency symbol, you will have to update the regex.

Using a whitelisting approach is easier, remove all chars that are not on your whitelist, digits and dots:

```
.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g,"")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ChE9Tu/1).

The `[^0-9.]+` matches 1 or more occurrences of any chars other than (the `[^...]` is a negated character class that matches the inverse character ranges/sets) digits and a dot.

JS demo:

```js
var nums = ["34 345 324.34 $",  "$34,345,324.34"];
var rx = /[^0-9.]+/g;
for (var s of nums) {
  console.log(s, "=>", s.replace(rx, ""));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For white space in the beginning of the string (or the end) use `str.trim();`, it will strip any trailing whitespaces from the beginning and/or the end of the string that contains them.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all **dots**, **spaces** and **dollars**, add the dollar sign (escaped) into your regex:

```
/,|\s|\$/g
```

or simply

```
/[,\s\$]/g
```

Demo:

```js
var num1 = "34 345 324.34 $"
var num2 = "$34,345,324.34"

var res1 = num1.replace(/[,\s\$]/g,""); //34345324.34
var res2 = num2.replace(/[,\s\$]/g,""); //34345324.34

console.log(res1)
console.log(res2)
```